# Leaflet Marker + Information Popup from JSON Data

Tags: json, ionic2, leaflet

I want to draw markers from Json Data on my project on Leaflet map

I'm currently doing with that way

```
L.marker([48.840346,2.319415]).addTo(map).
   bindPopup("<b>X<b>"<img style='width: 100%' src='http://i.imgur.com/XMVjS1s.jpg'/></div> ",{minWitdh:256} ");
```

I have to enter all the info by myself, and that's not the way i want to do it

But i have a Data.json

```
  {
      "title": "A",
      "lat": 48.841491,
      "long": 2.355989,

   },
    {
      "title": "B",
      "lat": 48.878849,
      "long": 2.312855,
      },
```

i want to do something like this

```
 L.marker([lat,long]).addTo(map).
   bindPopup("<b>title<b>"<img style='width: 100%' src='http://i.imgur.com/XMVjS1s.jpg'/></div> ",{minWitdh:256} ");
```

To get all The Data and render it as Marker on my Map?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the local json file, all you need to do is to download the json file with a HTTP GET request and add all points using a for loop.

I am not familiar with Ionic2 so I just assume there is a method `Http.get()` to send a GET request and return a promise with the data as JSON. Then you can do:

```
Http.get('local json file path')
    .then((data) => {
      // I assume there is an array in your json file
      data.forEach((point) => {
        L.marker([point.lat, point.long])
         .bindPopup("<b>" + point.title + "<b><img style='width: 100%' src='http://i.imgur.com/XMVjS1s.jpg'/>");  
         .addTo(map);
      });
    })；
```